# how to get/print the regularization loss/ l2 loss /weight decay value from optimizer in pytorch?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

described as the title.
I know the regularization loss in pytorch usually defined through the defination of the optimizer (**weight_decay**):
`torch.optim.SGD(params, lr=<required parameter>, momentum=0, dampening=0, weight_decay=1e-5, nesterov=False)`

how can I get the regularization loss value so that I can print it?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-inspect-the-regularization-loss-if-i-use-weight-decay-for-some-of-the-layers/28419), the regularization loss is never computed explicitly. So, what you need to do is calculate the loss on your own using the parameters. Something like

```
l2_loss = 0
for param in net.parameters() :
    l2_loss += 0.5 * torch.sum(param ** 2)
```